# How to select mismatch columns in SCD- Type2 through SAS

Tags: sas

We are Having SCD Type 2 tables almost 200 tables , with 250 columns in each table.

for EX: STUDENT details

```
STUDENT_ID VALID_FROM_DT  VALID_TO_DT        NAME    CITY   CONTACT_NO  BRANCH  
   1        04-April-2018   10-April-2018    XYZ     Chennai  12345     CSE
   1       10-April-2018   31-DEC-2055       XYZ     MUMBAI   87777     CSE
```

looking for some generic solution where to exact only mismatch columns for this case the output should be

OUTPUT :

```
STUDENT_ID VALID_FROM_DT  VALID_TO_DT         CITY   CONTACT_NO    
   1        04-April-2018  10-April-2018      Chennai  12345    
   1       10-April-2018   31-DEC-2055        MUMBAI   87777
```

Can this solution is possible , if so can it be some genric wher ei can use this for all my 200 tables.

Comment: What is a mismatch column? The output looks like it restricted some columns but that's all I see. And what have you tried?

Comment: What should output be when you also have STUDENT_ID=2 and the column with no change is CITY ?  Student 1 conditions make you want to 'drop' NAME, and Student 2 conditions make you want to 'drop' CITY.  What should output be when you have > 2 number of time frames and a column has some variations, For example  ID=3 BRANCH values bounce A->B->A->B->C or ID=4 CONTACT values are 11,11,11,11,22,11

Comment: Are the table name and id columns consistent, as in TABLE <foo> always has an id column <foo>_ID ?  Does you SCD management tool not have a 'changes' report feature ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i can loop with the code for 200 tables,But  can i know the code bit detail,  Since it is a SCD type 2 data (Where Student_id) is common , when there is a change in first record , it creates a new record in the table with the valid_from_DT , and valid_to_dt with latest processing records wiht the same Student_id ,   But the code is not comparing the first record with second record , and from that set we need to extract only Mismatch columns let us say the example output.

Comment: can you help a bit more   where
    1. I can compare the data with previous row based on primary key     
     2. how to get  exact mismatch columns fot example if there is a change in only 2 columns out of 100 columns in the table , from the result data set i want to display only the mismatched columns as given in the example. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

A large number of dimensional tables, each with a large number attribute columns is a big thing to examine.  For a generic solution, you will need to use metadata information to get a list of data sets in a library, check those data sets for indications of 'scd2-idness' (such as having an ID column named similarly to the data set name).  For each scd2 table you would again visit metadata to obtain the non-scd columns (any column that is not a record id, dimension id, or valid date range).  Then a process would be written pass through the data set and identify the cases of when an attribute value has or has not changed from its prior valid date range.

Consider some generated scd-2 data of arbitrary dimension name, having arbitrary attribute (i.e. column) names.  Some of the columns within a group are forced to be 'static' (which would be those columns that might be considered for dropping in your question)

```
%macro random_name(len=8);
  %local i result;
  %do i = 1 %to &len;
    %let result = &result.%sysfunc(byte(%sysfunc(ranuni(123))*26+65));
  %end;
  &result
%mend;

%macro make_data(lib=WORK, N=40);
  %local outcount i j p suffix out;
  %do outcount = 1 %to &N;
    %let out = dimtable_%random_name();
    %let idvar = &out._id;

    %local top cCount nCount cName nName namelen name;

    %let top  = %sysevalf ( 1000 * %sysfunc(ranuni(123)), FLOOR);
    %let nCount = %sysevalf ( 20 * %sysfunc(ranuni(123)), FLOOR);
    %let cCount = %sysevalf ( 20 * %sysfunc(ranuni(123)), FLOOR);

    %do i = 1 %to &nCount;
      %let namelen = %sysevalf(16 * %sysfunc(ranuni(123)), CEIL);
      %let name = ;
      %do j = 1 %to &namelen;
        %let name = &name.%sysfunc(byte(%sysfunc(ranuni(123))*26+65));
      %end;
      %local numvar&i;
      %let numvar&i = nattr&i._&name.;
    %end;

    %do i = 1 %to &cCount;
      %let namelen = %sysevalf(16 * %sysfunc(ranuni(123)), CEIL);
      %let name = ;
      %do j = 1 %to &namelen;
        %let name = &name.%sysfunc(byte(%sysfunc(ranuni(123))*26+65));
      %end;
      %local chrvar&i;
      %let chrvar&i = cattr&i._&name.;
    %end;

    data &out;
      do rowid = 1 to &top;

        if rowid = 1 or ranuni(123) > 0.8 then do;
          &idvar + 1;

          valid_from_dt = 0;
          valid_to_dt   = '01-jan-1970'd + floor(60 * ranuni(123));

          format valid: yymmdd10.;

          attrib 
            %if &nCount %then %do; %do i = 1 %to &nCount; &&numvar&i %end; length=8 format=6. %end;
            %if &cCount %then %do; %do i = 1 %to &cCount; &&chrvar&i %end; length=$20 %end;
          ;

          %if &nCount %then %do; array num %do i = 1 %to &nCount;  &&numvar&i %end; ; %end;
          %if &cCount %then %do; array chr %do i = 1 %to &cCount;  &&chrvar&i %end; ; %end;

          array staticN[0:&nCount] _temporary_;
          array staticC[0:&cCount] _temporary_;

          do _n_ = 1 to hbound(staticN); staticN(_n_) = ranuni(123) < 0.40; end;
          do _n_ = 1 to hbound(staticC); staticC(_n_) = ranuni(123) < 0.40; end;

          do _n_ = 1 to dim(num);
            num(_n_) = CEIL (1000 * ranuni(123));
          end;
          do _n_ = 1 to dim(chr);
            chr(_n_) = repeat(byte(65+26*ranuni(123)), 15 * ranuni(123));
          end;
        end;

        valid_from_dt = valid_to_dt + 1;
        valid_to_dt   = valid_from_dt + ceil(60 * ranuni(123));

        do _n_ = 1 to dim(num);
          if not staticN(_n_) then num(_n_) = CEIL (1000 * ranuni(123));
        end;

        do _n_ = 1 to dim(chr);
          if not staticC(_n_) then chr(_n_) = repeat(byte(65+26*ranuni(123)), 15 * ranuni(123));
        end;

        output;
      end;
    run;
  %end;
%mend;

options mprint;

%let SCD2_LIB = WORK;

proc datasets nolist noprint lib=&SCD2_LIB mt=data kill;
run;
quit;

%make_data(lib=&SCD2_LIB, n=1)
```

A generic scd-2 examiner macro is written to output a table that contains missing values (blanks) when an attributes value is unchanged from a prior valid date range.  It is not quite 'dropping' but is a good visual for seeing 'gaps' that mean unchanged information.

The macro is invoked by another process that discovers scd-2 tables and determines the numeric and character variables that will be examined as attributes that may have value changes.  Output is saved in a corresponding data set named *_changed.

```
%macro scan_scd(data=, idvar=, nvars=, cvars=);

  %local i nCount cCount;

  %let nCount = %sysfunc(countw(&nvars));
  %let cCount = %sysfunc(countw(&cvars));

  %do i = 1 %to &nCount; %local nvar&i; %let nvar&i = %scan(&nvars,&i); %end;
  %do i = 1 %to &cCount; %local cvar&i; %let cvar&i = %scan(&cvars,&i); %end;

  data &data._changes;
    if 0 then set &data(keep=rowid &idvar valid_from_dt valid_to_dt);

    retain
        %do i = 1 %to &nCount; &&nvar&i &&nvar&i.._was %end;
        %do i = 1 %to &cCount; &&cvar&i &&cvar&i.._was %end;
    ;

    set 
      &data (obs=0 rename=(
        %do i = 1 %to &nCount; &&nvar&i = ___nprv&i %end; 
        %do i = 1 %to &cCount; &&cvar&i = ___cprv&i %end;
      ))
      &data (obs=0 rename=(
        %do i = 1 %to &nCount; &&nvar&i = &&nvar&i.._was %end; 
        %do i = 1 %to &cCount; &&cvar&i = &&cvar&i.._was %end;
      ))
      &data;

    by &idvar.;

    if first.&idvar. then do;
      %do i = 1 %to &nCount; ___nprv&i = &&nvar&i; %end;
      %do i = 1 %to &nCount; &&nvar&i.._was = .; %end;
      %do i = 1 %to &cCount; ___cprv&i = &&cvar&i; %end;
      %do i = 1 %to &cCount; &&cvar&i.._was = ''; %end;
    end;
    else do;
      %do i = 1 %to &nCount; &&nvar&i.._was = ifn (&&nvar&i = ___nprv&i, ., ___nprv&i); %end;
      %do i = 1 %to &cCount; &&cvar&i.._was = ifc (&&cvar&i = ___cprv&i,'', ___cprv&i); %end;

      %do i = 1 %to &nCount; ___nprv&i = &&nvar&i; %end;
      %do i = 1 %to &cCount; ___cprv&i = &&cvar&i; %end;
    end;
  run;
%mend;
```

**scd-2 discovery and scan invocation**

The names of all the tables in some candidate library are gathered.

```
proc sql;
  create table scd_datasets as select libname, memname from dictionary.tables
  where libname = "&SCD2_LIB"
  ;
quit;
```

filename mprint and option mfile can store macro generated code in an external file for closer examination and study;

```
filename mprint "c:\temp\macro-source.sas" ;
%let rc = %sysfunc(fdelete(%sysfunc(pathname(mprint))));

options nomprint;
options mprint mfile;
```

Process each data set. Use dataset functions to access data set metadata information.

```
data _null_;
  set scd_datasets;
  scd_table = catx('.',libname,memname);
  scd_id_var = trim(memname) || '_ID';
  rowid_var = 'ROWID';
  from_dt_var = 'VALID_FROM_DT';
  to_dt_var = 'VALID_TO_DT';

  dsid = open (scd_table);
  if dsid then do;

    if varnum(dsid, scd_id_var) 
     & varnum(dsid, rowid_var)
     & varnum(dsid, from_dt_var)
     & varnum(dsid, to_dt_var)
    then do;

      length nvars $32000;
      length cvars $32000;

      nvars = '';
      cvars = '';

      do _n_ = 1 to attrn(dsid,'nvar');
        varname = upcase(varname(dsid,_n_));
        vartype = vartype(dsid,_n_);

        if varname ne upcase(scd_id_var)
         & varname ne rowid_var
         & varname ne from_dt_var
         & varname ne to_dt_var
        then do;
          if vartype = 'N' then nvars=catx(' ',nvars,varname);
          if vartype = 'C' then cvars=catx(' ',cvars,varname);
        end;
      end;

      %* Queue the invocation of the SCD-2 scanner macro for this particular data set;

      call execute (
%*        '%put NOTE: ' ||;
        '%nrstr(%scan_scd(' ||
          'data=' || trim(scd_table) ||
          ', idvar=' || scd_id_var ||
          ', nvars=' || trim(nvars) ||
          ', cvars=' || trim(cvars) ||
        '))'
      );
    end;

    dsid = close(dsid);
  end;
run;

options nomfile nomprint;
filename mprint;
```

Answer (score -1):

Chandana K

Yes it is possible, and you need to create a generic macro function to do this.
I see the example below with an example that you gave.

```
/* 1st function - table criteria */
%macro manytables(table, columns);
    data &table.(keep = &columns.); /* keep only the columns you want */
        set data_origin; /* Name of your source table */
    run;    
%mend;


/* Function wating 30 second for executuion*/
%macro waiting;
       data _null_;
              time_calc = sleep(1,30);
       run;
%mend;


%let BD = 0; /* initializes the count variable */

/* 2nd function - generate 200 tables about your criteria. */
%macro loop_200_tables;
    %do %while (&BD < 200);

         %waiting; /* to avoid network error and processing. */

         /* call your function */
         %manytables(STUDENT_details_&BD., STUDENT_ID VALID_FROM_DT VALID_TO_DT NAME CITY CONTACT_NO BRANCH);

         %let BD = %eval(&BD. + 1);
         %put STUDENT_details %eval(&BD. - 1) OK!;
         %PUT waiting new processing...;

    %end;

    %put finish;    
%MEND loop_200_tables;
%loop_200_tables;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i can loop with the code for 200 tables,But  can i know the code bit detail,